# my footer wont sit right on mobiles and tablets

Tags: html, css

i cant seem to get my footer sitting 100% width on mobiles and tablets, its fine on browsers! Please help, here is my css:

```
    .footerbox {
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px); (max-device-width : 1024px);
float :left;
width:100%;
height:300px;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
background-image:url(../images/aaheader12.jpg);
background-position:center bottom;
background-repeat : no-repeat;
font-family : Calibri;
font-size : 14px;
color : #000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete that @media line, it's not correct syntax (media queries get wrapped around rules, not nested inside them) and it sounds like you can just use the same styles for your footer across all devices anyway.

Comment: (That's not guaranteed to solve your problem, though—if it doesn't likely we'll need to know more about the setup of the page's HTML/CSS)

Comment: i have sorted it out, i did delete the line of css @media... but that was not the problem, at the foot of all my pages i still had `</section></copy></light>` and a few `</div>` that wernt helping i deleted those and it all sits perfectly, although it will not stretch to 100% now on browsers it does sit nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1022px),
only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px),
only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px),
only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px){your css}
```

This query for iPad, iPhone, mobile device and tablets with device width <1022px.